# How can I check if a certain string inside <span class="person_name"> equals to a line in a .txt file in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to check if the string contained in the "person_name" class (in this case, Natalie) is equal to another line in the text document.

```
with open ('names.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      url = urllib.request.urlopen("randomurl.com") 
      soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
      name = soup.find('span', {'class':'person_name'})
      if name.string == line:
         print("The names match")
```

Although

```
print(name.string)
```

prints "Natalie" as a test, the following if statement does not print anything even though the only line in the text document (Natalie) supposedly matches with the output of name.string.

```
if name.string == line:
    print("The names match")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading lines from a text file in Python gives them with a trailing newline. (Which is also part of the line after all.)

If the leading whitespace isn't significant in your case, clean the input up by using:

```
if name.string.strip() == line.strip:
    # ...
```

---

There's also the remote chance the [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) type that the BS docs say is the return value of [`.string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) doesn't implement comparison to `str`. In that case, you can use `str(name.string)` to convert it to a `str` explicitly, or [`name.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)